# Rails route can't expand model object to get ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a form in one of my views that looks like this:

```
<% form_for @user, url_for(:controller => :users, :action => :admin_edit, :id => @user.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select 'Confirmed', [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

The first line of it is raising a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. I *think* this is because the route (below) needs an ID, but isn't finding the ID it needs.

The `users#admin_edit` method is currently an empty definition. The route that points to it is:

```
post 'admin/users/:id/edit', to: 'users#admin_edit'
```

The `@user` object in question is set using

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

so the `:id` attribute is definitely set; I've verified this with the console.

Given that I've passed the ID explicitly to `url_for`, why can the route not expand the `@user` object to get its ID out? Or can it, and the issue is somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {:action => :admin_edit} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select 'Confirmed', [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you have set your routes as:

```
post 'admin/users/:id/edit', to: 'users#admin_edit'
```

Then your form could be as follows:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {:controller => ::users, :action => :admin_edit, :id => @user.id}, method: :post do |f| %>
 <%= f.select 'Confirmed', [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
 <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can get the `id` in your `UsersController` could look as follows:

```
def admin_edit
 @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```